# OpenCV and Gtest conflict in CMake

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, googletest

I am trying to do some Google Tests on my application and I met some conflicts between `OpenCV` and `GTest`:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)':
gtest-all.cc:(.text+0xdd84): multiple definition of `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a(ts_gtest.cpp.o):ts_gtest.cpp:(.text._ZN7testing8internal8GTestLogC2ENS0_16GTestLogSeverityEPKci+0x0): first defined here 
...
```

The `GTest` is used in `opencv_ts` library. Does anyone kows how to resolve these multiple deinitions?

I think that if I add just the libraries that I use from `OpenCV` it will be resolved, but I do not know how to do this. I have tried:

```
target_link_libraries(${Exec8name}_test ${OpenCV}/opencv_core.so* ... )

target_link_libraries(${Exec8name}_test ${OpenCV_LIBS}/opencv_core.so* ... )

target_link_libraries(${Exec8name}_test ${OpenCV_LIBS_DIR}/opencv_core.so* ... )
```

etc, but I get just errors of not found or `No rule to make tarket`

I have tried to remove one of the two, but I get errors of

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
...
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

option(test "Build all tests." OFF)

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME MyProj)

project(${EXECUTABLE_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")

include_directories(    src/main/cpp
            ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            )

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem 
                    system 
                    regex 
                    program_options)

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2 
              src/main/cpp/main.cpp

              src/main/cpp/solution2/MySol2.hpp
              src/main/cpp/solution2/MySol2.cpp
              )

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2   ${OpenCV_LIBS}
                        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                        )

if (test)
  find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

  enable_testing()

  include_directories( ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

  add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2_test 
            src/test/cpp/test_Sol2.cpp

            src/main/cpp/solution2/MySol2.hpp
            src/main/cpp/solution2/MySol2.cpp
            )


  target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2_test    ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
                            ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                            )

  target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2_test    ${GTEST_LIBRARIES}
                            pthread
                            )

  add_test(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2_test 
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2_test
          )

endif()
```

Can anyone tell me some ways to fix it?

Comment: You can unselect the OpenCV's configuration **BUILD_opencv_ts** with *cmake-gui* and rebuild the OpenCV. And try again.

Comment: As your make error, I think you'd better paste out your cmake file.

Comment: I have added the cmake file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "opencv_ts" module contains gtest, so you could just include the required OpenCV modules excluded "ts" module insted of all. For example:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc highgui)
```

Comment: I think your answare is better, because there will be less lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Add just the libs that I need like

```
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_Sol2   opencv_core
                                                opencv_highgui
                                                opencv_imgproc
                                                ...
                       )
```